# Change the range of numbers of dataset to text in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I am trying to change the number of ages in my dataset to text in python.

I used the following two ways but they are not working:

````
df.loc[((df['age'] >= 25) & (df['age'] <= 34)), 'age' ] = 'middle aged adults'
df.loc[((df['age'] >= 35) & (df['age'] <= 49)), 'age' ] = 'older adults'
df.loc[((df['age']) >= 50), 'age'] = 'elderly'```

Here is the second way: 

```df.loc[((df.age >= 18) and (df.age <= 24)), 'age' ] = 'young adults'
df.loc[((df.age >= 25) and (df.age <= 34)), 'age' ] = 'middle aged adults'
df.loc[((df.age >= 35) and (df.age <= 49)), 'age' ] = 'older adults'
df.loc[((df.age) >= 50), 'age'] = 'elderly'```

How would I be able to convert the numbers into text?
````

Comment: It's not possible to say from what you've given. You haven't stated the actual problem you're facing or given any representative data to help others understand the problem. You need a [mcve]

Comment: I think you're looking for Pandas `cut` function. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html